# Signal to Slot in QT Creator, where is connect() function?

Tags: qt, qt-signals, slot

In QT Creator, design mode, I right-click on a widget and select "Go to slot" and it creates a slot function for one of the widget's signals.

I would have thought that this would have generated a `connect()` function to create this connection, however, I can't find anything like that in any of the source code.

Where is the actual code that connects the widget's signal to the slot function?

Answer (score 8):

If you're using QtCreator's Designer, one of the outputs from this is a `.ui` file

Qt Designer ui files are an XML representation of your form's widget tree, and are processed by [`uic`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html), the *"User Interface Compiler"*

One of the features provided by Qt's ui format is [AutoConnect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect).

`uic` automatically generates code in the form's `setupUi()` function to connect your signals and slots.

The way it works is as follows:

Your slots must conform to the following format:

```
void on_<object-name>_<signal-name>(<signal-parameters>);
```

where `object-name` is the name of the object which emits the signal this slot is for.

Later, `uic` then generates code which calls [`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName)

Using Qt's reflection system, the `QObject` which has `objectName()`=*`object-name`* is found, and it's signal is connected to your slot.